# Intent missing only some extras in IntentService

Tags: android, android-intent, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, intentservice

I've been breaking my head with this for a few days so I hope someone can point out what I'm doing wrong. I'm creating an intent with 5 string extras and setting it to a PendingIntent to use with AlarmManager. However when the alarm triggers and I proceed with handling the intent inside onHandleIntent of my service class, there are only 3 extras in the Intent. Some code & screenshots below.

Intent creation:

```
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent("android.media.action.DISPLAY_NOTIFICATION");
        ;
        notificationIntent.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
        notificationIntent.putExtra("key1", "val5");
        notificationIntent.putExtra("key2", "val4");
        notificationIntent.putExtra("key3", "val3");
        notificationIntent.putExtra("key4", "val4");
        notificationIntent.putExtra("key5", "val5");
        return notificationIntent;
```

Pending Intent creation:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getActivity(), Integer.parseInt(obj.uniqueId), notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Inside intent service:

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

        if(intent != null) {

            if (intent.getExtras() != null) {

             String val1 = intent.getStringExtra("key1");
             String val2 = intent.getStringExtra("key2");
             String val3 = intent.getStringExtra("key3");
             String val4 = intent.getStringExtra("key4");
             String val5 = intent.getStringExtra("key5");

             // proceed with other stuff..

      }
   }
}
```

Based on some other answer's to questions similar to mine, I've also tried:

```
final Intent originalIntent = (Intent)intent.getExtras().get( Intent.EXTRA_INTENT );
final String val1 = originalIntent.getStringExtra("key1");
```

But the originalIntent is always null. I can't figure out why only 3 of the extras are available and the other 2 aren't. They are all String values so the discrimination is beyond my understanding :(

Debugger screenshots:
When intent is created -
[image]

When intent is read in intent service class -
[image]

I also tried doing `intent.setAction("",Math.random());` as suggested in some answers on SO but that resulted in the alarm not triggering at all.
Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What if you change that to `PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, Integer.parseInt(obj.uniqueId), notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);` ?

Comment: @ShreeKrishna: doing getActivity results in the alarm not  triggering at all

Comment: what is the value of `obj.uniqueId`? is it really unique or always the same?

Comment: @pskink: the unique id is unique to that object, like an id. It's used to set some properties on that particular obj in the intent service when the alarm triggers.

Comment: ok i missed `Intent.EXTRA_INTENT`, what is it used for? just use `intent.getStringExtra("key1")`, `intent.getStringExtra("key2")` etc

Comment: @pskink I do the same with the intent in onHandleIntent. However, only 3 extras are available; please see the debugger screenshots. Added intent service code as well.

Comment: what is `Intent.EXTRA_INTENT` used for?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114501/discussion-between-akdsouza-and-pskink).

Comment: You've added your "extras" to a broadcast `Intent` and then you claim that in your `Service` only 3 of the 5 show up. How about looking at the code that extracts the "extras" from the broadcast `Intent` in `onReceive()` and copies them to the `Intent` you use to call `startService()`. I think you'll find your problem is right there.

Comment: @DavidWasser Spot on! It was quite some time ago that I had addded & extracted the initial 3 extras, so when i added more I forgot to update the receiver to extract them too.. The issue is now fixed. I owe you a drink of your choice :) Would you mind adding your comment as an answer so that I can accept it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've added your "extras" to a broadcast `Intent` and then you claim that in your `Service` only 3 of the 5 show up. How about looking at the code that extracts the "extras" from the broadcast `Intent` in `onReceive()` and copies them to the `Intent` you use to call `startService()`. I think you'll find your problem is right there :-)